# Error when iterating over integers in python

Tags: python, loops

I am trying to calculate bernoulli polynomials for different n. I get an error that I can not iterate over integers, I have seen different posts, but still can't get it right. I read that I have to change integers to string in order to iterate over them, but still it does not work. Can you help?

```
    import scipy.special

def cub(x):
    return x*x*x

def bernoulli(k,n,x):
    a=scipy.special.binom(n, k)
    return cub(k/n)*a*x**k*(1-x)**(n-k)

def suma(n,x):
    s=0
    for str(k) in range (0,n):
        s=s+bernoulli(k,n,x)
    return s
```

The error is from iterating in the last paragraph. When I change str(k) to just k, I get the error 'int' object is not iterable.

Answer (score 1):

remove    `for str(k) in range (0,n):`

make it `for k in range (0,n):`

you cant convert an iterator in the function

```
import scipy.special

def cub(x):
    return x*x*x

def bernoulli(k,n,x):
    a=scipy.special.binom(n, k)
    return cub(k/n)*a*x**k*(1-x)**(n-k)

def suma(n,x):
    s=0
    for k in range (0,n):
        s+=bernoulli(k,n,x)
    return s

print(cub(10))
print(bernoulli(1, 2, 3))
print(suma(14, 2))
```

**output**

```
cub 1000
bernoulli -1.5
suma -16376.826530612321
```

Comment: Sorry, it does work indeed, I was missing one letter which made the error. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Replace `str(k)` to `k` in your for-loop. It's wrong syntax (and you are working with numbers, not with strings).

Answer (score 0):

Remove `str(k)` , you can't use a function returning something as an iterator.

```
import scipy.special

def cub(x):
    return x*x*x

def bernoulli(k,n,x):
    a=scipy.special.binom(n, k)
    return cub(k/n)*a*x**k*(1-x)**(n-k)

def suma(n,x):
    s=0
    for k in range (0,n):
        s=s+bernoulli(k,n,x)
    return s
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a function for the loop variable is a `SyntaxError`, because you can not assign a value to a function call.